# Stop Creation of Resources on Azure Subscription

Tags: azure, azure-policy

I need to stop creation of all resources on my azure subscription except for:

- Logic Apps
- Dashboards
- Solutions

the only way I can think of doing this right now is via Azure Policy, will anyone know how to write such policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where exactly you stock in creating azure policy? 
[Refer this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/tutorials/create-and-manage), You can restrict/allow upon resource types

Answer (score 2):

well, you basically need to use `not` and `anyof` in combination with `deny`:

```
"if": {
    "not": {
        "anyOf": [
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"
            },
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions"
            },
            {
                "field": "type",
                "equals": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards"
            }
        ]
    }
},
"then": {
    "effect": "Deny"
}
```

resource types might be wrong, but I'm not sure what are you after exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Policies require definitions (where the policy logic is written) and then a policy assignment (where the definition is assigned to a scope).  Policy definitions can be grouped into Policy Initiatives (AKA Policy Set Definitions).  These Initiatives can also be assigned to a scope. Scopes can be defined at the Resource Group level, Subscription level, or Management Group level.

Policies can be written and assigned through the portal by first creating a policy definition and then assigning it. IMO this can be a bit cumbersome when done through the portal. Or they can be deployed via ARM template. Unfortunately, the portal template deployment is not currently configured to deploy at anything other than at the resource group level (08/29/2019).  But it is much easier to write and deploy via the deployment API.  I use Postman to do this.

A subscription scoped (as you are describing) policy deployment can be done via PUT to the following URI.

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/:subscriptionId/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/mypolicydeployment?api-version=2019-05-01
```

Where :subscriptionId is Postman parameter notation for your actual Subscription ID.

You will need to obtain a bearer token to authenticate for the PUT request and that user must have permissions to deploy and assign policies. That is a whole other topic, you can learn more about that here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code).

Also, I supply a "Content-Type" = "application/json" header with my PUT request.

My this is my body payload for your policy.

```
    {
    "location": "westus2",
   "properties": {
   "mode": "Incremental",
   "template": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "subscriptionId": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
            "name": "my-deny-policy",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "westus2",
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "My Deny Policy",
                "policyType": "Custom",
                "description": "This policy DENYS all resource creation except, Logic Apps, Dashboards, and Solutions.",
                "mode": "All",
                "policyRule": {
                    "if": {
                        "not": {
                            "anyOf": [
                                {
                                    "field": "type",
                                    "equals": "Microsoft.Logic/workflows"
                                },
                                {
                                    "field": "type",
                                    "equals": "Microsoft.OperationsManagement/solutions"
                                },
                                {
                                    "field": "type",
                                    "equals": "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    "then": {
                        "effect": "Deny"
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "my-policy-assignment",
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-05-01",
            "location": "westus2",
            "identity": {
                "type": "SystemAssigned"
            },
            "properties": {
                "displayName": "My Policy Assignment",
                "policyDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/my-deny-policy')]",
                "scope": "[concat('/subscriptions/', parameters('subscriptionId'), '/')]",
                "notScopes": [],
                "parameters": {},
                "description": "This assignment contains my policy to DENY creation of all resources except logic apps, dashboards, and solutions.",
                "metadata": {}
            },
            "dependsOn": [
                "my-deny-policy"
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"parameters": {
    "subscriptionId": {
        "value": "XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX"
    }
   }
}
}
```

The deployment template contains a definition containing the policy you have described, as well as a policy assignment.  The policy assignment is set to "dependsOn" the policy definition.  This is because the policy assignment depends on the existence of the definition to deploy properly.  Otherwise, there will be a race condition that you will always lose.

Certain fields can be broken out into parameters as I have done with the subscription ID.  In order to apply at another subscription scope, simply change the parameter value and make sure your bearer token is authorized for that subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Make a **Custom RBAC** Role with "**ACTIONS**" only for these 3 you want.

Policy is OK here but it depends on the User role if he would be able to Unassign such policy from the Subscription.
To prevent user to do so:

- Apply policy on level higher then subscrption (mgmt group) where user has no rights.
- OR disallow user (in RBAC role) to work on Policy
  Definitions & Assigments.
- OR Create this Policy with Blueprint and
  set ReadOnly Lock for this Bluepring Assignment.